# Interpret list of integers as a float in Python

Tags: python, c, pointers, type-conversion

I am attempting to convert a C code snippet into python.

The purpose of said function is to take 4, 8-bit readings from a PLC, and decode them into a single float.

```c
float conv_float_s7_pc(char * plc_real)
{
char tmp[4];
tmp[0] = * (plc_real + 3);
tmp[1] = * (plc_real + 2);
tmp[2] = * (plc_real + 1);
tmp[3] = * (plc_real + 0);
return (* (float *) tmp) ;
}
```

Is there some Python magic that can perform this function cleanly?

While I am attempting to convert the above function, the more general question is, how would you perform memory "reinterpretations" such as this in python?

### Edit

This got me what I needed:

```python
import struct

def conv_to_float(plc):
    temp = struct.pack("BBBB", plc[0], plc[1], plc[2], plc[3])
    output = struct.unpack(">f", temp)[0]
    return output
```

Comment: The input is 4 integers, eg. 0 0 66 134
The ouput is 1 float, eg. 1.xxxxx * 10^yyyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) with the `f` format character

```
>>> import struct
>>> plc_real = "1234"
>>> struct.unpack("f", plc_real)[0]
1.6688933612840628e-07
```

Make sure you use `<` or `>` to set the endianness you need